# Struts2: My static param is override by the get method

Tags: java, struts2

I have a page who is divided by campus. Is basically the same page but I change the information depending to the campus.

The param "campus", set who is the currently used campus.

This work very well, for example if I access to *localhost/page/campus1/index.action*, the getCampus method return "campus1", has expected.

But if I access to *localhost/page/campus1/index.action?campus=campus2*, the getCampus() method return "campus2"; I try to avoid this behavior. I want the {campus} param was in the top of the priority and nobody can override him.

I tray using "excludeParams" from the "param" interceptor to exclude "campus" but now getCampus return null.

how can I exclude some get/post method from the param read by struts2?

or

can avoid the static param been override by others param?

EDIT:
I have a interceptor who say if the chosen campus is valid one or not.

If someone enter a real campus in the url, but put a "get method" with a wrong campus the test will pass but all the information will be wrong.

**My action**

```
@Action(value="{campus}/index",
    results={
        @Result(name=SUCCESS,location="/jsp/campusindex.jsp"),
    }
)
public String campusIndex(){
    return SUCCESS;
}
public void setCampus(String campus){
    this.campus=campus;
}
public String getCampus(){
    return this.campus;
}
```

**My jsp**

```
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%>
<s:label name="campus"/>
```

**My Interceptor**

```
 public String intercept(ActionInvocation actionInvocation) throws Exception {
     ActionConfig config = actionInvocation.getProxy().getConfig();
    String campus = config.getParams().get("campus");
    try{
        Campus.isaValidCampus(campus);
    } catch(Exception e){
        return "error404";
    }
    return actionInvocation.invoke();
}
```

Comment: Kind of a catch-22, but what does it really matter? If someone wants to craft a URL with a GET parameter, they could do the same thing with the "inline" pattern-matched parameter, so obviously it's not a security problem.

Comment: I change a little my question. My problem is the validatation of the campus parameter. I receive a diferent value of the campus in the interceptor than the action.